# Remote work for US company as Canadian citizen

Tags: united-states, freelancing, canada, taxes

Lately i was approached by several recruiters for US based companies for positions they have opened locally.
Two of them have assured me that there is no issues working as Canadian Citizen for US company remotely both full-time or freelance.

What are the pitfalls of such arrangement known to you?
Tax wise, where would they be paid? CRA or IRS?

Thank you

Comment: All offers were for remote work with some travel for training purposes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am Canadian citizen working in the US (from Toronto). Moved here back in 06. I can tell you that to be working for a US company, whether it's remote or physical, you'll need an SSN and a TN Visa. In order to get your SSN, you'll need a TN Visa first. You'll get your W-2 from the US and will have to file your taxes here in the US. Technically, you'll be treated as a US employee that's remotely located in Canada.

I don't believe there's legal issues since a TN visa is something you can get by crossing the border with an 'offer letter' from the company. There aren't any legal fees that your company have to pay. Possibly expenses for the visa ($200ish?) and perhaps some travel.

EDIT: You'll have to physically come to the US in the beginning to get your SSN and TN Visa. Every 2 years when you renew, you can just cross the border and then come back but use that time to see some cities (if financially possible).

Comment: "_In order to get your SSN, you'll need a TN Visa first._" But I know someone who is employed by a US company but he is not in US, never been there. He doesn't have a SSN or any US visa.